# Searching for a parallel copy program

Tags: linux, performance, parallel-processing

i'm looking for a software to copy files from hostS to hostS.

The first set of hosts (the sources can share a common filesystem) and the second set (the target) share another filesystem.

Perhaps gridftp can do that, but i can't find any example of n vs m.

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you really think copying files in parallel will be faster?

Comment: you mean that the bandwidth of the network is not the problem ?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I misunderstood your question. I was under the impression that this was meant "parallel" as in "multiple cores" as opposed to network.

Comment: Most sensible protocols like rsync: are windowed, so parallelling will achieve zero benefit. The constraint will almost certainly be on the network path and windowed TCP is already design to address this issue.

Comment: @TerryE the OP is talking about copying from a set of N machines/nodes/servers to a different set of M machines/nodes/clients, each with its own network connection

Comment: I agree and you make a valid point but the thing that I took from this Q is **a common filesystem** to **a common filesystem**.  If these are non-distributed them my comments still apply whether or not you've got M to N access nodes, unless the two sets are on a unified local fabric.  If they are DFS, then a generic performance discussion is meaningless as the characteristics of the different DFS vary so much.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not really what you were looking for, but food for thought nevertheless: you could (ab)use the bittorrent protocol. The n source nodes will act as seeds, the m destination nodes will act as peers. Pretty easy to setup (if you have a command-line client), and should scale well.

Comment: Not sure the bittorrent protocol know how to deal with multiples clients writing in the same file ...